# How to access an MTP USB device with python

Tags: python, mtp

How can I read from and write to my Galaxy Nexus phone, using MTP over a USB cable in python?
I'm on a windows 7 computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be to install ADB (android debugging bridge, part of the SDK) and launch it as a child process from python.  ADB can be used to, among other things, read from or write to, an android device.

Comment: Not really a solution since it requires the phone to have usb debugging enabled, which might be ok for most of us but not for normal consumers.

Comment: @Norfeldt Basically, you have to install drivers for your OS and download the ADB files. Do you have that working? Then use the subprocess.Popen to run ADB, for example: res, err = subprocess.Popen([adb, 'push', pc_source, device_dest], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

Comment: Not a solution since it requires USB debugging, and most users don't have this. MTP should work with USB debugging

Answer (score 5):

Calibre, a popular ebook management program, has python and C source code to transfer files over an MTP connection.  http://code.google.com/p/calibre-ebook/downloads/list

Comment: URL to browse the relevant code in trunk: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kovid/calibre/trunk/files/head:/src/calibre/devices/mtp/

Comment: It seems a bit complicated.

Comment: the python modules seem to be unusable with a plain python interpreter

Answer (score -5):

Simply connecting a **USB** cable between the phone and computer should work.

It may be necessary to enable **MTP** transfers in the settings menu on your phone.  The menu selection location is likely to be different on different versions of android and different phone models. Try a google search for "galaxy nexus enable mtp".  Make sure to include your android and phone version in the search.

Make sure it is a good quality **USB** cable.  Poor quality cables will not make a good connection and therefor not work reliably.

A file management dialog comes up immediately on my desktop after hooking up a usb cable between my phone and laptop showing both the phone internal storage and SD card.  This allows me to transfer files both ways directly to the phone SD storage (**Linux Mint** <-> **LG Android ver. 5.1**)

Note that it is also possible to transfer files using Bluetooth.

After establishing a connection, you would need to find the device name.  Then it would be possible to open the device using standard python file constructs, i.e. `popen()`, etc.

Comment: It's not about cable. It's about how can you write a file on the phone (via FTP) with Python code. It's **not** just as simple as `with open('mtp://SamsungA3/hello.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('hello')`...

Comment: I down voted this - I agree it's not about the cable.  The cable matters, but the code is not as straight forward as the other code used to open local files.