# Download files from USB-connected smartphone to Windows by script (or Python)

Tags: python, windows, usb, file-transfer

Is there a way to download to Windows (and later erase) files on an USB-connected smartphone? I'd like to create an automatic download and backup of pictures for a family smartphone...

I've seen hints only about Unix, and no indication on how copy files via USB on Windows. Finally, I'd like to use Python, so I looked into the libusb package, but this seemed far away from any files&folders model. I have not even been able to find any "mountpoint" on Windows (which I assumed to exist from the presentation of the smartphones in Windows Explorer).

Answer (score 0):

If I connect my android  smartphone to an Windows OS, normaly it gets its own drive letter after allowing the data connection by the phone.

So I would be able to make a backup of pictures with a simple batch-script or even with a python script ( using the functionalities of the os modul).

Comment: Can you tell me how the simple batch-script needs to look like? I have not even seen a windows directory of the smartphone. E.g., it does not appear in the wxPython directory listing. I assume that's the case because it does not have a drive letter associated. Windows Explorer seems to implement an entirely different (USB) protocol to present the smartphone like a regular drive.

Comment: I have to correct myself. I do not use windows very often and thought I had seen an drive letter with my phone in the explorer. But I have checked again and there is not drive letter as you said. Windows seems to use MTP to connect the phone. Maybe you´ ll find aditional infomations here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161747/how-to-access-an-mtp-usb-device-with-python

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you running?

On Windows 10, at least, when my phone is plugged in I can right click on it in File Explorer (This PC), and choose 'Import Pictures and Videos', which then looks through all the folders on your phone for its picture and video files.  You can then import them to your PC, and from there copy them to a location of your choice.

This is probably the easiest way of achieving what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create an automatic download, as I wrote. Of course the smartphone is accessible via the Windows Explorer, but I know of no programmatic interface.