# How to read image files from a Camera (Nikon D5600) with Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera, mtp

Forgive me if I've left anything out or goofed up formatting conventions; this is my first time posting on this sort of forum.

So I've got a Nikon D5600 that I'm using as part of an (extremely basic) image analysis setup. I'd like to be able to use images from it without having to manually transfer the files over each time I run a test, but I've had some trouble getting access to the files.

To be clear, **I don't want to capture screenshots of a video**; I understand that this is possible, but the resolution is about 1/3 smaller in video, which is a bit of an issue for my application.

So, when I was 6 hours more naive, I plugged in the camera via USB to my (Windows 10) desktop, tried calling the image using the exact (well, I did change the slashes out) file path windows gave me in the properties screen:

`img = cv2.imread("This PC/D5600/Removable storage/DCIM/314D5600/CFW_0031.jpg")`

That didn't work.

I checked that the command I was using wasn't the issue by copying the picture to another drive:

`img = cv2.imread("D:/CFW_0031.jpg")`

That worked.

So I think, and think is a bold claim here, that it's something to do with the "This PC" bit of the path. I've read some old (circa 2009) posts about MTP and such things, but I'm honestly not sure if that's even what this camera uses, or how to get started with that if it is in fact the correct protocol.

I've also tried using pygrabber (I believe it's a wrapper of direct show, though my terminology may be wrong) to control the camera via python, but that also didn't work, although I did manage to control my webcam, which was interesting.

Finally, I attempted to set the [assign a letter drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1355859/how-can-i-assign-a-letter-drive-to-a-digital-camera-after-i-connect-via-usb) to the camera, but found that the camera wasn't in the manager's list of discs. It's entirely possible I just did this method wrong, but I don't quite see how.

***Edit regarding comment from Cristoph***

-I just need to be able to use the image files in python, probably with opencv. I suppose that counts as reading them?

-I've attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVlYF.png) of what the "This PC" location looks like in the file explorer. The camera shows up under devices and drives, but doesn't have a drive letter.

Comment: those `This PC` paths don't actually exist. Windows Explorer pretends they do. maybe first to go `This PC` and show us how this camera is presented (screenshot). -- **if** that camera presents as a USB "webcam", you can request **still frames**, which can be full resolution, unlike video, and will take the appropriate time to expose. there's this [utility by nikon](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/webcam-utility.page) -- if you want to access the camera's **storage** via **MTP**, there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161747/how-to-access-an-mtp-usb-device-with-python

Comment: files aren't "called". they can be read, written, copied, moved, deleted, ... and some can be executed. I would strongly suggest that you edit your question and clarify why you say "call", or change the word